# ES6 - Template strings hack for IE 11

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using a long HTML Template script in JS file, like:

```
var TEMPLATE = `
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ul>
</div>`;
```

It works in all browsers(including Chrome, Safari, Firefox & EDGE) but not in Internet Explorer 11, 10.

Can you suggest how I can fix this?

Comment: Try using Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

Comment: It's because you're using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which [aren't supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals), you can change it to a _normal_ string or as @Michelangelo has said, use Babel

Comment: Yes, I got it that "template literals aren't supported in IE". @Michelangelo, Can you describe how can I use Babel? I'm using AngularJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template literals not working in IE11 when "use strict" directive is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871705/template-literals-not-working-in-ie11-when-use-strict-directive-is-used)

Comment: @om. No, this is not a programming class and I am not a teacher. The docs are clear. You have to figure this one out on your own.

Comment: Got it @Michelangelo, I have converted my code with https://babeljs.io/repl and now it is working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't need any of the advanced features available in template literals (such as `${foo}`), you might also consider using regular quotes and just escape the new lines to prevent syntax errors, like so:

```js
var list = '\
    <div>\
        <ul>\
            <li>first</li>\
            <li>second</li>\
            <li>third</li>\
        </ul>\
   </div>\
';
```