# Collapsible tree diagram v4 and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I am using this d3 Javascript library:  https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

When i use Google Chrome it works fine, but when I use Internet Explorer 11. I get an error in:

```
 path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                                 C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                                    ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                     ${d.y} ${d.x}`
```

The problem is the sign `. I know that Internet Explorer and Chrome "read" code differently, but how can i modify my code to work in Internet Explorer or in both?

Comment: Apparently IE11 [doesn't support template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40872280/8237835). You can probably modify the code (laboriously) by using plain quotes `"` instead and then replacing all of the `${...}` with string concatenation like we used to do in the old days. Also, is there any particular reason for this spacing? Because that might make things slightly harder.

Comment: No don't mind the spacing. Can you give an example of how you would write it ?

Comment: Looks like Zim's got you covered in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If template literals are not supported, just build the path by concatenating `Strings` and variables as you would have done prior ES6:

```
path = "M " + s.y + " " + s.x + " C " + ((s.y + d.y) / 2) + " " + s.x + ", " + ((s.y + d.y) / 2) + " " + d.x + ", " + d.y + " " + d.x;
```