# Invalid character in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have this string variable inside javascript function. When I run this page in IE with this script I am getting invalid character error at for below line.

```
let displayString = `${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871705/template-literals-not-working-in-ie11-when-use-strict-directive-is-used

Comment: IE does not support the backticks notation (template literals).

Comment: @AnisR. How can I fix this code to run in IE

Comment: Do not use template literals or Use babel in your build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backticks notation (template literals) is not supported in IE.

A possible workaround would be:

```
let displayString = seconds < 10 ? '0' : '';
displayString += seconds;
```

It seems what you want is to pad left with zeros, so that the number is always at least two digits. To achieve that, you could use `padStart()`:

```js
//pad left with the character '0' so that length is at least 2 digits
console.log("7".padStart(2, '0'));
console.log("17".padStart(2, '0'));
```

Comment: How about this one ``pointer.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * value / (timePercent)}deg)`;``

Comment: I did this but I am getting rotate is undefined error `var test = (360 * value / (timePercent));
        pointer.style.transform = rotate(testdeg);`

Comment: The backtick notation is for strings. I assume what you wanted to do is `pointer.style.transform = "rotate(" + testdeg + ")";` ?

Comment: Yes I wanted to do like you have suggested but getting the testdeg is undefined error

Answer (score 0):

(`)Template string literals is new features of ES6

So, This is not supported in IE browser.

Please refer the below link for more information [ES6-Template-Strings Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

Comment: This should probably be a comment not an answer, as @AnisR one

Comment: Its supported chrome 41+ version, Its working in chrome browser as well. and for reference give link. This also key note of answer.