# issue with the code not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using one code which is working in all browsers but not in IE11 or IE10

how can i fix it

```
$(`#${formID} textarea:not(.ctype)`).each(function(k) {
```

because it seems the usage of the ` is problematic and IE does not like it

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct.   IE does not support  template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: Don't use them, or use a transpiler.  There is no way to force IE to support them.

Comment: Use concatenation: `'#' + formId + ' textarea:not(.ctype)'` instead

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40871705/215552

Comment: Please [use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=backtick+in+ie).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to mock template literals in IE, the closest thing you can do is format a string and replace placeholder values with an entry map.

```js
// Custom formatter function
function frmt(str, obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(acc, [key, val]) {
    return acc.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\{' + key + '\\}', 'g'), val);
  }, str);
}

// jQuery selector
const selector = frmt('#${formID} textarea:not(.ctype)', { formID: 'my-form' });

console.log(selector);

$(selector).each(function(textarea) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <textarea>A</textarea>
  <textarea>B</textarea>
  <textarea class="ctype">C</textarea>
</form>
```

---

If you want to make the code portable, you can write a jQuery plugin:

```js
// Custom selector plugin
(function($) {
  $.sel = function(selector, repl) {
    return $(Object.entries(repl).reduce(function(acc, [key, val]) {
      return acc.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\{' + key + '\\}', 'g'), val);
    }, selector));
  };
})(jQuery);


$.sel('#${formID} textarea:not(.ctype)', { formID: 'my-form' })
  .each(function(textarea) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <textarea>A</textarea>
  <textarea>B</textarea>
  <textarea class="ctype">C</textarea>
</form>
```